# Cannot find assembly sitecore.wffm.mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, .net-assembly

I am new to Sitecore and trying to create a custom WFFM field. The tutorial I am following tells me to add assembly Sitecore.WFFM.MVC [(link to tutorial)](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/working_with_actions_and_validations/fields/create_a_custom_field_type) but I cannot find this assembly anywhere. Any help is appreciated. I am using Sitecore 8.2. The class I which is unresolved is Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.SingleLineTextField

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Sitecore 8.2 the reference you need to add is `Sitecore.Forms.Mvc`.

I suppose the tutorial you're using is for an older Sitecore versions.